# Snap duration not working on fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I need to set snap duration greater than slot duration, but fullcalendar v5 override snapduration with slotduration.

For example: I need 15 mins slots but if click on any background event, it should select 60min.

Is there a way to reach this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Your question is likely to be closed unless you edit it to show what you've tried, why that didn't work, etc ... Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. Can you provide your current code, and also some sample event data which is realistic for this situation. And please explain more clearly to- you are talking about snapDuration, which relates to dragging an event and where it will be dropped. But then you talk about "click on any background event, it should select 60 mins". What do you mean by this? You want to automatically change the length of the event to 60 mins? Or it should only be able to snap onto times which are on the hour (e.g. 1pm, 2pm etc only)? Or something else? Try to give clearer details, please

Comment: @ADyson I am showing users availability as background events. Now I want only that availability needs to be clickable and on click I am showing a custom popup for booking confirmation. So for this I am showing 15 mins slots, so users can book 30mins, 45 mins, 60mins slots. So if user is allowed to book for 30 mins, it should automatically select two rows(15mins + 15mins), and if allowed to book 45 mins, it should select three rows(15mins + 15mins + 15 mins) and so on.

Comment: Ok. So how are you deciding whether the user is allowed to book 30 mins or 45 mins or whatever? Is that information available as a variable in your JavaScript? Or is it pre-determined by the size of these background events?

Comment: @ADyson yes it is available as JavaScript Variable

Comment: So, you can check that variable when the user has made a selection, check the length of of their selection, and if it's incorrect, you can then alter the length of the selection (or just display an error, whatever you prefer).

Comment: @ADyson I understand that, but it doesn't feel good for UI point of view. I would like to allow user click on background event it should show that time selected as default.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It would likely happen so fast that the user would hardly notice, or not see it at all.

Comment: Also if this value is fixed and available when the page loads, you could set https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultTimedEventDuration in the calendar options, so then any click (rather than drag) to select would automatically create an event of the length specified there.

Comment: @ADyson I have already tried defaultTimedEventDuration, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the defaultTimedEventDuration option definitely works in itself...so perhaps your usage of it wasn't quite correct. It would really help if you show the code you have currently so we can see where that usage is going wrong, and hopefully help you fix it.

Comment: @ADyson here is code for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/mc7jdgru/8/

Comment: @RahulMittal did you find any solution? i have exact asme problem.